# Counting multiples of 3 up to a given number

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I'm attempting a practice problem in Codeforces that requires you to find the number of multiples of 3 less than or equal to a given number. I have written the following code but it gives a TLE once the test case reaches the order of 10<sup>8</sup>.

```
int x = Reader.nextInt();
int count = 0;

for(int i = 3; i<=x; i++){
    if(i%3 == 0){
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Is there any way I can further optimize this code? The test cases max out at 10<sup>9</sup>.

Comment: Can you think of a simple mathematical formula which computes the result directly, without the need for a loop?

Comment: Is it dividing the given number by 3? Oh no

Comment: It might be better to include the entire program if this is most of the program. We have a lot of space for code.

Comment: TLE? What's that? Time limit exception?

Comment: Ignoring the closed-form solution of this particular problem, I would suggest you use [`IntStream.iterate(3, i -> i+3)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-)

Comment: @Alexander Why would you recommend this?

Comment: @gnasher729 You can do much more with it than obtain the final count.

Comment: @Evorlor Time limit error.

Comment: @Alexander I have never used the IntStream interface before before. I will definitely look into it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Evorlor; TLE is an abbreviation of [tag:time-limit-exceeded] .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are insisting on counting, instead of computing the answer, you can optimize your counting loop by just looping over the multiples of 3:

```
for(int i = 3; i <= x; i += 3) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: you missed a trick here, appending count++ in the loop

Comment: Yeah this works. I needed to count it as it was mentioned explicitly in the question. But I hadn't even figured the simple computation until a few minutes ago.

Comment: @dfhwze how would that work?

Comment: for(int i = 3; i <= x; i += 3, count++);

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this trick! I haven't messed around with loop parameters like this before.

Comment: @dfhwze That “trick” doesn’t make the code run any faster, and can lead to errors if you forget/don’t notice the trailing semicolon.  I would call it out reviewing other people’s code here on Code Review.  I certainly didn’t “miss” it, and highly recommend against it.  When iterating over a non-trivial body, with two or more iterators, incrementing all of them in the increment portion of the `for()` statement is proper, and can improve readability of the code.

Comment: That "trick" was a lightweight joke. Didn't mean to step on anyone's toes here.

Comment: @dfhwze My compiler would refuse to compile it. It gives a warning when a semicolon immediately follows an if or for because it is most likely a bug, and any warning is turned into an error.

Comment: @gnasher729 You can configure whether warnings are compile errors. Feel free to play around with this. But in the end, it's all just semantic shenanigans. Go with the solution as provided in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use your brain, not brute force. How would you solve the problem if it were presented in a math test, and you couldn't use a computer?

Your solution requires \$O(x)\$ time; it should be possible in \$O(1)\$.

Comment: The title does state _counting_, not _computing_ :p

Comment: Yep, I figured. I'll keep the question up as a reminder to me that most simple problems will have simple solutions.

Comment: @dfhwze  That's only since someone butchered the title.  It originally said *finding*.

Answer (score 4):

Using lambdas you can use multithread easily, it should improve your results:

```java
IntStream.rangeClosed(3, x).parallel().filter(n -> n%3 == 0).count()
```

or, in case you need long values:

```java
LongStream.rangeClosed(3L, x).parallel().filter(n -> n%3L == 0L).count()
```

---

I tested it with the following example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Instant start, end;
        long x = 24923869024L;
        long count = 0;

        // normal loop
        start = Instant.now();
        for (long n=3L; n<=x; n++) {
            if (n%3L==0L) count++;
        }
        end = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("method 1, result = "+count+", time = "+Duration.between(start, end));

        // non-parallel stream
        start = Instant.now();
        count = LongStream.rangeClosed(3L, x).filter(n -> n%3L == 0L).count();
        end = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("method 2, result = "+count+", time = "+Duration.between(start, end));

        // parallel stream
        start = Instant.now();
        count = LongStream.rangeClosed(3L, x).parallel().filter(n -> n%3L == 0L).count();
        end = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("method 3, result = "+count+", time = "+Duration.between(start, end));

    }
```

with the results:

````
method 1, result = 8307956341, time = PT33.55S
method 2, result = 8307956341, time = PT40.611S
method 3, result = 8307956341, time = PT12.637S
```
````

Comment: Could you be specific about *what* is better?  I'm guessing you mean the elapsed time, rather than (say) memory usage or energy consumed.  Also, *why* this improves it is also worth mentioning (given that the parallelisation overhead is probably fairly high compared with the work).

Comment: I was talking only about total time, it's true that I've not taken into account any other factor like memory or energy. Also, it's possible that results may vary according the computer. I'm sure there would be a way more clever and optimized solution (and I'll be glad to know it); however, in my opinion, simpler solutions are good enough in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

If I were to compute the answer, I'd do (language shown is C#):

```js
var n = 1e8;
int v = n / 3;
```

6 has two multiples of three less than or equal to it: `6 / 3 == 2`
127 has 42: `127 / 3 == 42.3333`, thus `Math.floor(127 / 3) == 42`.

Likewise, `3 * n` will have `n` multiples of three, including three itself.

---

Rather than having to iterate `1e8 - 2` times in a for-loop (similar amounts are often used for benchmarking tests), we just have to boil it down to a single integer division.

Comment: I'm using Java here. Doing long/int division in Java ignores the decimal section anyways. But thanks for the answer, I'll keep it in mind for a later use.

Comment: You know, in java 11, that actually compiles :P we have autotyping now

Comment: I've been noticing Java lags behind on new features.  Lambdas weren't introduced until Java 8 whilst they were a part of C# for much longer.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].